# Flutter web : can i use window.onload function on index.html? and i need receive header data,

Tags: flutter, web, jwt

when i use url_launcher, and open flutter web site

```
Future<void> _launchInBrowser(String url) async {
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(
    url,
    forceSafariVC: false, 
    forceWebView: false, 
    headers: <String, String>{'strToken': 'strTokenstrToken'},
  );
} else {
  throw 'Web Request Fail $url';
}
```

when open flutter web site, can i get a headers data??
i want get 'strToken'.